# Android resource compilation failed after android gradle version update

Tags: android, android-studio, build, build.gradle

I am developing an android app, everything was going fine until i updated gradle version to 3.2. Whenever i try to build or sync the project it shows 'Android resource compilation failed'

```
Output:  C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\base\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugFeatureResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2316: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
 Command: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\fc444429c9ac9f1db8d9bb3790bf9413\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \ -o \              C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\base\build\intermediates\res\merged\feature\debug \       C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\base\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugFeatureResources\merged.dir\values\values.xmlDaemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0\
```

The error comes up in this line

```
 <item name="textviewprofile" type="id">Logout</item>
```

I tried to delete the logout element, but the changes does not reflect after build and it still shows up.It says you cannot edit values.xml. I also tried to clean and invalidate the project but that also didn't worked. I have been trying it for several days but cannot fix it.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance for it

Answer (score 0):

did you already tried deleting the .gradle file located in your root project dir? That sometimes works for me.
Gradle keeps a cache of the task it runs so by deleting the .gradle folder you are invalidating the gradle cache and forcing to redo it again.

Comment: I think it is the same as invalidate cache and restart, if yes, then yeah, i tried it.